# Неверный результат суммы

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Пытаюсь сделать вывод суммы итоговой экономии в заказе в woocommerce. Из таблицы оплаченного заказа должны быть взяты произведение количества (qtty) и значение ставки(price). Далее формируется итоговая сумма этих произведений по каждому товару(sum). Вроде бы скрипт валидный, но значения выходят не всегда верные, может не вижу чего, не подскажете?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var sum = 0;
    var qtty = $('strong.product-quantity').text().slice(2);

    $("label.qtty").each(function() {
      var price = $(this).text();
      sum += parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qtty);
    });

    alert(sum);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
            <tr class="woocommerce-table__line-item order_item">

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name">
        <a href="/produit/creme1/">Creme1</a><label class="qtty">2</label> <strong class="product-quantity">×&nbsp;1</strong>   </td>

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">9,95<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span>    </td>

</tr>

<tr class="woocommerce-table__line-item order_item">

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name">
        <a href="/produit/creme2/">Creme2</a><label class="qtty">2</label> <strong class="product-quantity">×&nbsp;5</strong>   </td>

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">49,75<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span>   </td>

</tr>

<tr class="woocommerce-table__line-item order_item">

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name">
        <a href="/produit/creme3/">Creme3</a><label class="qtty">1</label> <strong class="product-quantity">×&nbsp;1</strong>   </td>

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">9,95<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span>    </td>

</tr>

        </tbody>
```

Comment: Запятые != точки. Я про разделитель дроби.

Answer (score 1):

`var qtty = $('strong.product-quantity').text().slice(2);` — это значение только первого элемента, которое получается один раз вне цикла, и используется для всех остальных элементов. Нужно перенести это дело внутри цикла и взять каждый элемент отдельно:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var sum = 0;

  $("label.qtty").each(function() {
    var price = $(this).text();
    var qtty = $(this).siblings('.product-quantity').text().slice(2);

    sum += parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qtty);
  });
  
  console.log(sum);
  
});
```

```css
.qtty { color: red; }
.qtty + * { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="woocommerce-table__line-item order_item">

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name">
      <a href="/produit/creme1/">Creme1</a><label class="qtty">2</label> <strong class="product-quantity">×&nbsp;1</strong> </td>

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">9,95<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span>
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr class="woocommerce-table__line-item order_item">

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name">
      <a href="/produit/creme2/">Creme2</a><label class="qtty">2</label> <strong class="product-quantity">×&nbsp;5</strong> </td>

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">49,75<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span>
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr class="woocommerce-table__line-item order_item">

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name">
      <a href="/produit/creme3/">Creme3</a><label class="qtty">1</label> <strong class="product-quantity">×&nbsp;1</strong> </td>

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">9,95<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span>
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!

Answer (score 0):

Значения разные т.к. в функции вы складываете единственный элемент `$('strong.product-quantity')` cо ВСЕМИ элементами `$("label.qtty")`

Comment: Отформатируйте ответ, пожалуйста.